# Difference between one-to-one and one-to-many relationship in a database

Tags: database, database-design

When having a one-to-one relationship in a database the other table has a foreign key ID (in this example). And in a one-to-many relationship the table contains many foreign keys.

But does the database know whether this is a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship? Are the relationships that I make in an ER-Diagram only to indicate where there should be foreign keys when making the actual tables?

What is the difference between one-to-one and one-to-many relationship in a database?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a sense, all the relationships we talk about are not *known* to the database, they are constructs we have invented to better understand how to design the tables.

The big difference in terms of table structure between one-to-one and one-to-many is that in one-to-one it is possible (but not necessary) to have a bidirectional relationship, meaning table A can have a foreign key into table B, and table B can have a foreign key into the associated record in table A.  This is not possible with a one-to-many relationship.

One-to-one relationships associate one record in one table with a single record in the other table.  One-to-many relationships associate one record in one table with many records in the other table.

Answer (score 9):

To enable one-to-one relationship you need to add unique constraint to foreign key. It is not possible to have two foreign keys for each table as it will be impossible to create records.

Comment: It's not good design, but it would be possible if it's truly a 1:1 (not 1:0...1) and you create one of the tables with the foreign key column nullable.

Answer (score 6):

Im having trouble understanding what the actual question is.

Your analysis is for the most part correct, in that if you have a 2 tables, and table2 has a foreign key to table one, it could be either a one-to-one or a many-to-one.

Your sentence "And in a one-to-many relationship the table contains many foreign keys."

The table of the 'many' side still contains one column that is a foreign key, its just that more than one row can have the same foreign key value (many rows point to one parent).

Also note that you can put the foreign key on the parent table, to the child, instead of the other way around.  In this way, you can prevent one-to-many if you want to do that.  Also note that in this way, more than one parent can share a child, which might or might not be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The database-level equivalent of a 1:1 vs. 1:m is having a unique index on the foreign key column. Note that this will only work for 1:1, NOT 1:0..1, as `null` is considered when evaluating uniqueness. There are workarounds for this restriction, but that's it at the basic level.

Comment: To be exact it's a unique *constraint* that matters. An index is incidental because an index is just a performance optimisation feature. In a DBMS that follows the SQL standard (most DBMSs except for SQL Server and its derivatives) nulls are *ignored* in a uniqueness constraint - the unique requirement only applies to rows that don't have nulls in the constrained columns.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly by example, a product has only one product code, so it's one-to-one relationship (**product <-> ABC123**), but a customer can purchase more than one product, so it's one-to-many relationship (**person <->>>product**).

Answer (score 1):

well, you are right, this relation is important for you, but not for db itself. When you have two tables, one with your basic information, and another one with your detailed information.. for both tables you are you, so it is one-to-one relation, you can not map your data to somebody else.

Now add third table "cities" and one of your information points to city you live in - this is example of one-to-many (one city can be used, and should be used for many people).

one-to-many / one-to-one just show how your tables interact. And all the time, you want to "save" rows/columns in table not duplicating them you will use one-to-many relation with another table. Or many-to-many :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a table with two attributes A and B. If A is a candidate key and B is not then the relationship between A and B is 1 to many. If both A and B are candidate keys then the relationship is 1 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given table A and B if

1. A and B have a strict 1 to 1 relationship
2. For every B instance, there will always be an A instance

The best approach is to make the primary key of B also a foreign key referencing A. This is also called "Table per Type Inheritance" and the "is a" relationship. There are other ways to enforce a unique foreign key, but using the primary key makes the relationship clear in the schema and in ER diagrams.

Of course there are always other scenarios, and if your design doesn't meet both of the criteria above, you'll have to use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from this tutorial (using NET Core, Entity Framework): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#entity-diagram-showing-relationships

## Answer Content

1. Diagrams
2. Explanation
3. Diagram code

#### 1. Diagrams

##### At Visual Studio 2019

[image]

##### At Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

[image]

#### 2. Explanation

Relationships are read as follows:

- **1 to ***

  - one-to-many relationship.
  - For every row in a table, you can have multiple rows in another table.
  - Example: One student can assist to many classes, or, one writer can have written hundred of books.
  - In the diagrams above, a single student has many enrollments (to different courses or classes).
  - In OOP you could see this as a collection of items inside a class.
- **1 to 0.. 1**:

  - one-to-zero-or-one relationship.
  - This is the same as **1 to 1**, One-To-One relationships, but with possible nullable value at the second end of the relationship.
  - For every row in a table, you can EITHER have one row in another table, OR no-row in another table.
  - Example: A student may not be enrolled at any class.
  - In OOP you could see this as a nullable id value to a class name (`int? ClassID` in C#) inside the student class.
- And we have to mention *** to ***:

  - many-to-many relationship.
  - Which in the diagrams is in fact represented using a middle table: Table 1: `Instructor` - Middle table: `CourseAssignment` - Table 2: `Course`.
  - Every row in table 1, can have many rows in table 2, AND at the same time every row in table 2, can have many rows in table 1.
  - Example: An instructor may teach many courses, and that same course may have more than one instructor assigned.
  - In OOP you could see this as 2 different classes, referring each other THROUGH a collection of an intermediate class.
  - See example below:

[image]

#### 3. Diagram Code

Additionally, taking a look at how the above diagram is generated programmatically, could be of some help:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Data
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(SchoolContext context)
        {
            //context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // Look for any students.
            if (context.Students.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            var students = new Student[]
            {
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo",   LastName = "Anand",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Gytis",    LastName = "Barzdukas",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Yan",      LastName = "Li",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Peggy",    LastName = "Justice",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Laura",    LastName = "Norman",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Nino",     LastName = "Olivetto",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01") }
            };

            foreach (Student s in students)
            {
                context.Students.Add(s);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var instructors = new Instructor[]
            {
                new Instructor { FirstMidName = "Kim",     LastName = "Abercrombie",
                    HireDate = DateTime.Parse("1995-03-11") },
                new Instructor { FirstMidName = "Fadi",    LastName = "Fakhouri",
                    HireDate = DateTime.Parse("2002-07-06") },
                new Instructor { FirstMidName = "Roger",   LastName = "Harui",
                    HireDate = DateTime.Parse("1998-07-01") },
                new Instructor { FirstMidName = "Candace", LastName = "Kapoor",
                    HireDate = DateTime.Parse("2001-01-15") },
                new Instructor { FirstMidName = "Roger",   LastName = "Zheng",
                    HireDate = DateTime.Parse("2004-02-12") }
            };

            foreach (Instructor i in instructors)
            {
                context.Instructors.Add(i);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var departments = new Department[]
            {
                new Department { Name = "English",     Budget = 350000,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2007-09-01"),
                    InstructorID  = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Abercrombie").ID },
                new Department { Name = "Mathematics", Budget = 100000,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2007-09-01"),
                    InstructorID  = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Fakhouri").ID },
                new Department { Name = "Engineering", Budget = 350000,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2007-09-01"),
                    InstructorID  = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Harui").ID },
                new Department { Name = "Economics",   Budget = 100000,
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2007-09-01"),
                    InstructorID  = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Kapoor").ID }
            };

            foreach (Department d in departments)
            {
                context.Departments.Add(d);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var courses = new Course[]
            {
                new Course {CourseID = 1050, Title = "Chemistry",      Credits = 3,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Engineering").DepartmentID
                },
                new Course {CourseID = 4022, Title = "Microeconomics", Credits = 3,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Economics").DepartmentID
                },
                new Course {CourseID = 4041, Title = "Macroeconomics", Credits = 3,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Economics").DepartmentID
                },
                new Course {CourseID = 1045, Title = "Calculus",       Credits = 4,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Mathematics").DepartmentID
                },
                new Course {CourseID = 3141, Title = "Trigonometry",   Credits = 4,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Mathematics").DepartmentID
                },
                new Course {CourseID = 2021, Title = "Composition",    Credits = 3,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "English").DepartmentID
                },
                new Course {CourseID = 2042, Title = "Literature",     Credits = 4,
                    DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "English").DepartmentID
                },
            };

            foreach (Course c in courses)
            {
                context.Courses.Add(c);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var officeAssignments = new OfficeAssignment[]
            {
                new OfficeAssignment {
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Fakhouri").ID,
                    Location = "Smith 17" },
                new OfficeAssignment {
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Harui").ID,
                    Location = "Gowan 27" },
                new OfficeAssignment {
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single( i => i.LastName == "Kapoor").ID,
                    Location = "Thompson 304" },
            };

            foreach (OfficeAssignment o in officeAssignments)
            {
                context.OfficeAssignments.Add(o);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var courseInstructors = new CourseAssignment[]
            {
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Kapoor").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Harui").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Zheng").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Macroeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Zheng").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Calculus" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Fakhouri").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Trigonometry" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Harui").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Abercrombie").ID
                    },
                new CourseAssignment {
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Literature" ).CourseID,
                    InstructorID = instructors.Single(i => i.LastName == "Abercrombie").ID
                    },
            };

            foreach (CourseAssignment ci in courseInstructors)
            {
                context.CourseAssignments.Add(ci);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var enrollments = new Enrollment[]
            {
                new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.A
                },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.C
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Macroeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                        StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Calculus" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                        StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Trigonometry" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Anand").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Anand").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Barzdukas").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Li").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    },
                    new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Justice").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Literature").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                    }
            };

            foreach (Enrollment e in enrollments)
            {
                var enrollmentInDataBase = context.Enrollments.Where(
                    s =>
                            s.Student.ID == e.StudentID &&
                            s.Course.CourseID == e.CourseID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (enrollmentInDataBase == null)
                {
                    context.Enrollments.Add(e);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```