# laravel 5 one to one relationships

Tags: laravel-5

I was hoping to get a little input on my relationships.  I have a simple migration like so

```
Schema::create('project_docs', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('projectId')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->foreign('projectId')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->longText('whatData');
    $table->longText('whoData');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('projectId')->default('');
    $table->string('clientStatus')->default('');
    $table->string('contactName')->default('');
    $table->string('projectName')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I was hoping that would produce a one to one relationship, but when I open the database within MySQL Workbench and display the EER diagram, it shows that projects can have one to many project_docs.

I know within their Models in Laravel I can define their one to one relationship, do I need to change the one to many relationship produced by the above or do I just ignore it?

Thanks

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751923/difference-between-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationship-in-database) question should help you in your quest for knowledge

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

I believe this change will make MySQL Workbench show it as one to one relationship in the diagram.

```
Schema::create('project_docs', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');

    // Note UNIQUE here.
    // Personally I wouldn't define a default. Maybe add it as nullable?.
    $table->integer('projectId')->unsigned()->unique(); 

    $table->foreign('projectId')->references('id')
                                ->on('projects')
                                ->onDelete('cascade');

     $table->longText('whatData');
    $table->longText('whoData');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Quick aside do you really need the field `projectID` in your `projects` table?